# Wrong default markers Google Maps v3

Tags: internet-explorer, google-maps

I have a problem with markers Google Maps v3. Only with IE7 and IE8. First load webpage, default markers appear on the map. If I zoom in on the map, it works all right.

Here you have a sample image. Red, pinks and purple markers are mine.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/NG2r5.jpg

Comment: A line of code is worth a thousand pictures.

Comment: sorry, to much line code. You can see this problem in develop site www.sinbarrera.es - thks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The repeating marker is there because of your final `{}` in variable `markers`. Remove it and take out the trailing comma at the end of your final entry.